# Template inheritance with static properties (Service Locator Pattern)

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, properties, static

I've been trying to implement the Service Locator pattern using a templated base class and inheriting from it:

```
    // Header File
    namespace one {
    template <class I, class N>
    class Locator {
    public:
        static void initialize() {
            service = &nullService;
        }
        static void provide(I* newService) {
            if (newService == 0) {
                initialize();
            } else {
                service = newService;

        }
        static I& get() { return *service; }
        virtual ~Locator() {
            if (service != &nullService) {
                delete service;
            }
    private:
        Locator();
        static I* service;
        static N nullService;
    };
    }

    // Source File
    #include "Locator.hpp"

    namespace one {
    template<class I, class N>
    I* Locator<I, N>::service;

    template<class I, class N>
    N Locator<I, N>::nullService;
    }
```

**class I** is the instance class, and **class N** is the null service class.
And for the derived class:

```
    // Header File
    namespace two {
    class ExampleLocator : public one::Locator<Service, NullService> {}
    }

    // Source File
    namespace one {
    template class Locator<Service, NullService>;
    }
```

When I try and use this implementation,

```
    int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
        two::ExampleLocator::initialize();
        two::ExampleLocator::get().doSomething();
    }
```

gcc fails compiling with the following errors:

- undefined reference to one::Locator::initialize()
- in function one::Locator::get(): undefined reference to one::Locator::service

What am I doing wrong?

NOTE: I could get the project to compile by re-declaring Locator's static properties in the Derived class's cpp:

```
    // Alternative Derived class Source file
    namespace one {
    template<class I, class N>
    I* Locator<I, N>::service;

    template<class I, class N>
    N Locator<I, N>::nullService;

    template class Locator<Service, NullService>;
    }
```

NOTE2: the Derived class is in a different namespace than the Locator class.

Comment: Pubby already answered your question; I'd just add you also have a bug in the destructor. You should only `delete service` if it's not equal to `&nullService`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Template definitions must be visible in all translation units that use them. Move your code in the .cpp file to your .hpp file.

See: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: @JuanPablo If it's the same error then update question. Otherwise post a new one.